# z score for binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, poisson-distribution, z-score

I have seen people use z-score of 6 for statistical significant p-value (10^-9) in binomial distribution. What is the basis for chosing z score of 6 and not 3 in those cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choice of $\alpha$ for the critical p value/z score is arbitrary. In sociology there are many sources of error so $z=1.96$ can be acceptable.

Sometimes when rejecting the null hypothesis has big implications we want to be very sure that there is no false negative so we require a large z value. Also where experiments are precise enough that getting the required sample size for $z=6$ isn't prohibitively expensive we can require a large $z$ value. The typical example of this is in theoretical physics. The discovery of the Higgs Boson had a $z=5$ level of significance.